# getting fields out of RDD[string]

Tags: scala, rdd

I'm trying to pull out the 7th and 9th fields from an RDD. I used the following code

```
val logData = sc.textFile("path",2).map(item => {val comps=item.split(" "); (comps(6).toFloat, comps(8).toFloat)})
```

But, I got the output as

(x1,y1)

(x2,y2)

(x3,y3)

where as I need the output as

x1  y1

x2  y2

x3  y3

Can anyone give me a solution to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean as a String, such as "0.54 0.123"? If so, you could replace:

```
(comps(6).toFloat, comps(8).toFloat)
```

with

```
s"${comps(6).toFloat} ${comps(8).toFloat}"
```

(or you can use `f"${comps(6).toFloat}%0.3f ${comps(8).toFloat}%0.3f"` or similar instead of `s"..."` for greater control over formatting).

Comment: it worked. Now i basically need to
x*x y*y

I tried 

.map(_.toFloat).map(x => x*x) But it did't work